# Question about roboearth network

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a small question about using roboearth with ROS. I want to use the roboearth with turtlebot kinect for object detection.

My question is

1. Do you need the robot laptop and workstation to be connected to internet in order to use the roboearth features?
   I am using the workstation pc and robot pc without internet, I just network them using usb routers.
2. As it says, you need to have an account on the roboearth to save your data and then calling it back for detection, can this be done without internet connection?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109586/question-about-roboearth-network/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2013-12-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to exchange data with the RoboEarth database via the Internet, you will need to have an Internet connection. Not sure if you can use the object recording software without connection and store the objects locally -- if that's not described in the documentation, how about trying out if there is a button for that?

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0